# Understanding lazy initialization singleton in dagger2 ScopedProvider by Gregory Kick

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, dagger-2

I am reading Dagger2's source code, and in `ScopedProvider` there is static field `UNINITIALIZED` which is to indicate that the `instance` field is not yet initialized. I've already read and understand the *double-check-lazy-initialization* idiom, but why is it necessary to define the `UNINITIALIZED` field instead of just using `null`? Is it something about the JVM?

```java
/**
 * A {@link Provider} implementation that memoizes the result of a {@link Factory} instance.
 *
 * @author Gregory Kick
 * @since 2.0
 */
public final class ScopedProvider<T> implements Provider<T> {
    private static final Object UNINITIALIZED = new Object();

    private final Factory<T> factory;
    private volatile Object instance = UNINITIALIZED;

    private ScopedProvider(Factory<T> factory) {
        assert factory != null;
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // cast only happens when result comes from the factory
    @Override
    public T get() {
        // double-check idiom from EJ2: Item 71
        Object result = instance;
        if (result == UNINITIALIZED) {
            synchronized (this) {
                result = instance;
                if (result == UNINITIALIZED) {
                    instance = result = factory.get();
                }
            }
        }
        return (T) result;
    }

    /** Returns a new scoped provider for the given factory. */
    public static <T> Provider<T> create(Factory<T> factory) {
        if (factory == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        return new ScopedProvider<T>(factory);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's a lazy null-safe initialization. Imagine if the factory returned null and that code, instead of UNINITIALIZED, was using null as the sentinel value. Every time get() is called it would enter the synchronized block because it doesn't know the null is has is actually the factory result and not just an uninitialized state.

This code allows the factory to return null and have the result be correctly memoized in the volatile field so that subsequent reads don't incur the full synchronized overhead.